# How To Use Reserved Keywords in Android SQLite JOIN Query?

Tags: android, sqlite

My field names are from,to. I have tried table_name.from but get sqlite error ... same query works well in  mysql... Also I tried 'table_name.from',`table_name.from`,etc. nothing worked. Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Change the column names. That's the best and easiest option.

Comment: @Prerak sola I know that will work... but, If I change the field name I need to update many code on both server and in Android...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always try to use brackets

```
  table_name.[from]
  table_name.[to]
```

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

It isn't realy standard SQL but it works.
But I would just advise you to change the column-names.

Comment: how can I use the bracket with table_name.from...?

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood your question I thought you were talking about tables, I edited my post ;)

Comment: The same way I have tried all other thing expect this... Thanks man... It works... thank you very much... saved me from doing lot of rework.